# Como seleccionar y comparar entre fechas resultados entre dos tablas?

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pagos
WHERE pagos.id = usuarios.id AND mes =< '$mes' AND ano =< '$year' )
```

Estoy intentando mostrar o seleccionar los usuarios que no han realizado pagos en un rango no mayor a un mes, logro que me muestre si el ano es diferente pero no logro mostrarlo si el mes lo es , que puedo estar haciendo mal.

Comment: Primera vez que veo ese operador `=<` . Tal vez si pruebas con `<=` te funcione. Pero el operador 'diferente de' es `<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te has complicado mucho. No sería más fácil escoger directamente de pagos los registros de un mes en un año?

```
SELECT * FROM pagos 
WHERE mes = '$mes' AND ano = '$year';
```

Ejemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b494/4